# Using \immediate\write18 when lineno package yields spurious text

Tags: shell-escape, write, lineno, bash

I am getting spurious text in the output of `\immediate\write18` when the `lineno` package is used.  The  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301)  below yields the following in the file `foo.tex`:

[image]

If one comments out the line that includes the `lineno` pacakge, I get the desired results:

[image]

I would have thought that disabling the features of the `lineno` pacakage would resolve this problem.  However, the following lines did not resolve this issue:

```
    \nolinenumbers
    \renewcommand{\thelinenumber}{}%
    \renewcommand\LineNumber{}%
```

#### Question:

How can I disable this issue within the `\OuputToFile` macro and still use the features of the `lineno` pacakge in the pdf?

### Notes:

- Do **not** run this if you have `foo.tex` in the current directory as that will be overwritten.
- I need to include the `lineno` package to produce the pdf and gater the stats that I am trying to output at the end of that process. I would prefer to avoid having to do an extra run without this package as that would add a lot of additional processing time.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[mathlines,pagewise]{lineno}% <-- Commenting this out yields desired results

\makeatletter
    \immediate\write18{printf "\\n" > foo.tex }% Initialize File
    \NewDocumentCommand{\OuputToFile}{%
        m% string to output
    }{%
        %% None of these solve the issue
        %\nolinenumbers
        %\renewcommand{\thelinenumber}{}%
        %\renewcommand\LineNumber{}%
        \immediate\write18{printf '\@percentchar s' 'string = "#1"' >> foo.tex }%
        \immediate\write18{printf "\\n" >> foo.tex }%
    }
\makeatother

\def\MyString{$\OuterMacro{\InnerMacro{X}}$}


\begin{document}
    Output to file: 
    \OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\dXXX{X}}$}}%
    \OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\eXXX{X}}$}}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: In recent versions of LaTeX, ``\\`` is `\protected`, so it doesn't expand in the `\write`. `lineno` redefines ``\\`` to be robust, so you have to use ``\string\\``.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Yep that fixed it. Thanks. Please post answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the [2020-02-02](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltnews31.pdf) release, the `\\` macro was made (ε-TeX) `\protected`, as opposed to (LaTeX) robust as it was before, so if you now write:

```
\immediate\write17{hello\\world}
```

it will print `hello\\world` in the terminal (or to a file).  Previous versions (ones `lineno` was based on) had `\\` just robust (declared with `\DeclareRobustCommand`), so using it in a bare `\write` would make it explode (you'd need to use `\protected@write` instead).  `lineno` still has an old non-`\protected` version, so when you load it, BOOM!

You can either redefine `\\` to make it `\protected` in your document:

```latex
\NewCommandCopy\oldbackslash\\
\protected\def\\{\oldbackslash}
```

or (likely more meaningful in this case) use `\string\\`:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[mathlines,pagewise]{lineno}% <-- Commenting this out yields desired results

\makeatletter
    \immediate\write18{printf "\string\\n" > foo.tex }% Initialize File
    \NewDocumentCommand{\OuputToFile}{%
        m% string to output
    }{%
        \immediate\write18{printf '\@percentchar s' 'string = "#1"' >> foo.tex }%
        \immediate\write18{printf "\string\\n" >> foo.tex }%
    }
\makeatother

\def\MyString{$\OuterMacro{\InnerMacro{X}}$}


\begin{document}
    Output to file: 
    \OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\dXXX{X}}$}}%
    \OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\eXXX{X}}$}}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: (not sure if it's a good idea to copy paste definitions everywhere. Better just redefine it using the old definition)

Comment: @user202729 It's not, but it's also not a good idea to redefine a core LaTeX macro like ``\\``, so we have what we have (and that's part of the reason I suggested the `\string` method over the redefinition)

Comment: No, what I mean is if you redefine anyway, why not redefine it using the existing definition instead of hard coded (something like `\let\oldbackslash=\\ \protected\def\\{\oldbackslash}` (not tested...)

Comment: @user202729 Ah, I see. Maybe `\NewCommandCopy\oldbackslash\\ \protected\def\\{\oldbackslash}` should work (`\NewCommandCopy` instead of `\let` because ``\\`` is robust), but I'm not sure how well that survives when ``\\`` is redefined in a table and such.  Anyway, added to the answer. Thanks!